# Is no initialization the same as initialization to null?

Tags: java

If you declare an object like so:

```
Object x;
```

does it initialize as `null`?

For example, will `(x == null)` be `true`?

Answer (score 11):

If `x` is a field, it will be `null` by default. If it is a local variable, you have to explicitly initialize it before you use it. This is outlined in [JLS §4.12.5: Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Comment: To be precise, it becomes `null` in the constructor.

Comment: @GGrec Not necessarily, what about static fields?

Comment: Static fields become `null` at runtime. The reason I commented above is because I was thinking of `final` fields, which must be initialized in the constructor. Please correct me if I'm wrong, although this can develop into another discussion.

Comment: Well, all fields get their values at runtime. :) (Exception: `final` fields of primitives whose value is a constant expression, in which case the fields are actually elided away and the constant value is inlined to the code that uses it.) Static fields become `null` at class load time.

Comment: @GGrec No, each field is initialised to null ***before*** the constructor.

Comment: Reference: [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5): *The default initialization of any object happens-before any other actions (other than default-writes) of a program.* A section above, you also have this comment: *Although it may seem a little strange to write a default value to a variable before the object containing the variable is allocated, conceptually every object is created at the start of the program with its default initialized values.*

Comment: Doesn't this mean that `Object x;` and `Object x = null;` are _not_ the same? i.e. Even though the end result is that `x` is `null` in both cases, the latter case results in two assignments (default then explicit) whereas the former results in a single assignment (default).

Comment: @damo Would seem that way, yes. It could even matter, if `x` were `volatile`; you could use that as a happens-before barrier to safely publish a non-volatile field which is initialized at declaration and appears before `x` in the code -- the publication would be safe as long as the reader read `x` before reading that other field.

Comment: @arshajii I believe that's incorrect, though I don't have time to look up the JLS right now. But if you had a field `int x = 123` and the object were incorrectly published (e.g. `this` escaping to another thread from the constructor), another thread would be allowed to read `x == 0` as well as `x = 123`.

Comment: @yshavit I believe you are right; I worded my comment poorly. When you have `x = 123`, `x` still has a value prior to this, and that value is its default value (0 in this case). What I meant was there won't be two assignments in the bytecode when you explicitly assign via `= ...`. Similarly, there won't be *any* assignments in the bytecode when you perform no explicit assignment.

Comment: @arshajii Ah, yes, we're in agreement then. And more importantly, we're probably in agreement with the JVM spec, which trumps both of us. ;)

Answer (score 1):

member variables are initialized to null and local variables are not initialized and the initial value is set by you.

Note:- null is definitely a value. Its the value which doesnt refer to any object.